How to extract MF4 channel data
I have a MF4 file and asammdf gui show it has data in 3 different channel groups, but when I try to extract those data using python I only can see the data in the "Channel Group 0". Can somebody show me how to get the other Channel group data. Thank You
import asammdf
mdf = asammdf.MDF("mf4files/bmwx7/00000002.MF4")
for group_index, vg in mdf.virtual_groups.items():
    # print(vg.cycles_nr)
    if vg.cycles_nr > 0:
        print(vg.groups)
        print(dir(vg))
        included_channels = mdf.included_channels(group_index)[group_index]
        print(included_channels)
        
        for sigs in mdf._yield_selected_signals(group_index, groups=included_channels):
            print(sigs)


I try to convert this mdf4 file to csv using asammdf gui and then I get the data in from group 21 and group 22.
